# How to load json from rest endpoint in Adobe Animate CC using javascript

Tags: json, rest, animate-cc

I am using the latest version of Adobe Animate CC and have created an HTML5 canvas project. I am not sure how to go about calling a REST endpoint and parsing the response data using the latest version of Animate CC. In previous versions (i.e. Edge Animate), you were able to use JQuery. Any info I find in my searches is outdated and pertains to older versions. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, figured it out. In Animate CC I added the  URL to the CDN version of jQuery under Actions->Global->Include